# Prove that $\iint_S f(x,y) dx dy = \ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right) \cdot \int_{a}^{b} f$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $b > a > 0$ and $S$ be the region bounded by the curves $xy = b$, $xy = a$, $y = bx$, $y = ax$ in the first quadrant. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, show that:

$\iint_S f(x,y) dx dy = \ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right) \cdot \int_{a}^{b} f$

I don't really know even begin this problem.

What I did:

$u = xy$ and $v = y/x$

$x = \sqrt{\frac{v}{u}}$ and $y = \sqrt{uv}$

Jacobian: $(\frac{x,y}{u,v}) = \frac{-1}{2u}$

How do I continue from here?

Comment: Curves of bounds are suggesting a certain transformation of variables.

Comment: I think you mean $\iint_{S}f(xy)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$? If so, try setting $u=xy,v=\frac{y}{x}$ and proceed formally.

Comment: @MatthewH. I tried, but couldn't finish it.

Comment: Write your calculations in your post and someone will help you.

Comment: @MatthewH. Done

Comment: I'm getting $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}=\frac{1}{2v}$. Also, $(x,y)\mapsto (xy,\frac{y}{x})$ maps $S$ to the rectangular region $[a,b]\times [a,b]$ and your integral becomes $$\iint_{[a,b]^2}\frac{f(u)}{2v}\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$$ Can you finish?

Comment: @MatthewH. Yes, thank you